# Product Id and Store Id does not return any value in Magento

Tags: php, magento, controller

I wrote this code in my block file called "Myquestion.php" and trying to retrieve its value in the phtml file

This file lies in `/app/code/local/Maven/Questionanswer/Block`

```
    public function getProductId()
        {
            $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
            return $product_id;
        }

    public function getStoreId()    
        {
            $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
            return  $storeId;
        }

    }
```

Now I have the phtml file in `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/questionanswer`

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" placeholder="<?php echo $this->getProductId();?>">


<input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="<?php echo $this->getSoreId(); ?>">
```

But failing to retrieve any value. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the html code... It should have value instead of placeholder... But I am still not getting the value

Comment: Can you show us your xml code?

Answer (score 1):

First check the class in your .phtml file like,

```
echo get_class($this);
```

If it is not returning any or correct class then check your block layout file that you defined.

And make sure the function `getProductId()` is really returning any values. Make sure clear you cache.